# Can I get a specific number of posts per author and order by date in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a pretty basic query_posts call:

```
query_posts(array(cat=>3,author=>$userID,posts_per_page=>12))
```

This is getting 12 posts from the third category for a set of authors. The only piece I'm missing is I want those 12 to be made up of two posts each of my 6 authors. The order by date is fine, they don't need to be grouped by author.

Is there a way to pull posts this way?

Comment: After writing my answer I realized that you wanted it to be ordered by date and not necessarily grouped by author. My answer will still work but it will sort by author, then date (you may end up with different dates from different authors...).

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I don't think this is possible with just one query since there isn't (to my knowledge) a way to specify how many posts per author.

It will add to your load time a little bit, but you might have to split it out into 6 different queries to get it to work.

You can do this by using WP_Query (your probably shouldn't use `query_posts` as it will change your main query) and wrapping each query in the specific author block:

```
$author1 = new WP_Query(array('cat'=>3,'author'=>$author1ID,'posts_per_page'=>12));
if($author1->have_posts):
    while($author1->have_posts()):
        $author1->the_post();
        ?>
        <!--Insert HTML etc. here-->
        <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query(); //reset the query object if running in the loop
```

Then do it for each of your other authors and that should do the trick.

Hope that helps. If there is a way to do one query I would definitely like to know since multiple queries can slow down page load.